# How to update the "LastModifiedDate" timestamp automatically on parent entity when adding/removing child entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, parent-child

**Is there a way to *automatically* enforce parent entity to be timestamped as having been modified, if any of its dependent child items are added/deleted/modified?** The key word is *automatically*. I know this can be done by manipulating the DbEntry's EntityState or by manually setting the timestamp field in the parent, but I need this done on a number of parent-child entities in a system, so the desire is to have EF (or a related component) automatically do this somehow.

---

### More Background and Examples

Let's say we have an **Order** and **Order Items** (1-many). When **order items** are added/removed from an order, the parent **order** itself needs to be updated to store the last modified timestamp.

```cs
public interface IModifiableEntity
{
    DateTime LastModifiedOn { get; set; }
}

public class Order : IModifiableEntity
{
    // some Order fields here...

    // timestamp for tracking when the order was changed
    public DateTime LastModifiedOn { get; set; }

    // list of order items in a child collection 
    public ICollection<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    // other order item fields...
}
```

**Somewhere in application logic:**

```cs
public void AddOrderItem(OrderItem orderItem)
{
    var order = _myDb.Orders.Single(o => o.Id == orderItem.OrderId);
    order.OrderItems.Add(orderItem);
    _myDb.SaveChanges();
}
```

I already have a pattern in place to detect modified entities and set timestamps automatically via EF's `SaveChanges`, like this:

```cs
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var timestamp = DateTime.Now;

    foreach (var modifiableEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries<IModifiableEntity>())
    {
        if (modifiableEntity.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            modifiableEntity.Entity.UpdatedOn = timestamp;
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

That works great if any direct fields on an `IModifiableEntity` are updated. That entity's state will then be marked as `Modified` by EF, and my custom `SaveChanges()` above will catch it and set the timestamp field correctly.

The problem is, if you only interact with a child collection property, the parent entity is not marked as `modified` by EF. I know I can manually force that via `context.Entry(myEntity).State` or just by manually setting the `LastModifiedOn` field when adding child items in application logic, but that wouldn't be done centrally, and is easy to forget.

**I DO NOT want to do this:**

```cs
public void AddOrderItem(OrderItem orderItem)
{
    var order = _myDb.Orders.Single(o => o.Id == orderItem.OrderId);
    order.OrderItems.Add(orderItem);

    // this works but is very manual and EF infrastructure specific
    _myDb.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;

    // this also works but is very manual and easy to forget
    order.LastModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;

    _myDb.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Any way I can do this centrally and inform EF that a "root" entity of a parent-child relationship needs to be marked as having been updated?**

Comment: you can mark the entity "order" as modified, that will make EF track it as modified

Comment: if you use EFCore try _myDb.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;_

Comment: @henocsalinas, thanks, but that's exactly what I said _I do not_ want to do, because it would have to be done manually for other situations like this one. I need an automated way to do this.

Comment: Maybe you could define an IModifiableEntityDependent which has a property dependentOf which returns an IEnumerable of other IModifiableEntity that should be updated too? In your case that would be dependentOf => new[] { Order }.Where(e => e is not null). You should have lazy loading and proxy creation enabled in case those entities are not loaded and of course handle that interface in your SaveChanges overload.

Comment: Hi @Jiveman, I have a similar scenario to handle, could you please provide update if you have any. TIA

Comment: @JayaSundeep, I decided that this was not worth the extra work on the project I was on, and there seemingly wasn't anything simple to do, so this is still unresolved unfortunately.